# OOP with resource and header declaration: invalid keyword

Tags: c++

I am creating a project that uses a dll resource named GUI.dll for its dialogs.
At first, when I had everything in the .cpp except a few lines (that were in the header), the GUI.cpp looked like

```
class AuswertungsGUI : public Dialog
    {
    public:
    AuswertungsGUI() : Dialog(DA_Window, "GUI")
    {
        InitMsgMap();
    }
```

that worked. But now I've split everything up into a header GUI.h with the class declaration and the GUI.cpp with the implementation. I obviously don't know how to create the appropriate dialog out off the resource:

GUI.h:

```
#ifndef AUSWERTUNGSGUI_H
#define AUSWERTUNGSGUI_H

#include <Origin.h>
class AuswertungsGUI:public Dialog
{
public:
    AuswertungsGUI();  
    ~AuswertungsGUI(); 
private:
//...
};
```

GUI.cpp:

```
#include "GUI.h" //Definition der Klassen: AuswertungsGUI, ...

AuswertungsGUI::AuswertungsGUI():Dialog(DA_Window, "GUI") 
//Dialog( LPCTSTR DlgName, LPCTSTR DllName )
{
    InitMsgMap();
}

AuswertungsGUI::~AuswertungsGUI() //Desktruktor
{
    printf("Im Desktrutor\n");
    this->Close();
}
```

Error at GUI.h in line `class AuswertungsGUI:public Dialog`. The compiler says (translated):  `Invalid keyword, expcted identifier of base class`, then 
`class/struct not found` and then `error in declaration of datatype`

Comment: Is `Dialog` declared in `Origin.h` ? If not, you're probably missing a header...

Comment: No it is not. Thank you!! That happens if you rewrite one file into two... Make an answer and I accept or I will delete this post, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the compiler is complaining that `Dialog` isn't a base class identifier because it hasn't encountered its declaration (and thus can't subclass it, as it doesn't "know" it).

Include the header that contains `Dialog` and it'll be fine.